# Will OSX Lion support filevault encryption on bootcamp partitions?

Tags: bootcamp, filevault, macos

I'm thinking of migrating to bootcamp (from Parallels for speed), but need encryption. Apple has said Lion will have "whole disk" 128-bit encryption - any guesses on whether this includes bootcamp partitions?

Comment: I am closing this because it is speculation about unreleased software. See [this meta post](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/399/how-to-handle-lion-questions/400#400).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I think it is unlikely, as Windows would need some way to decyrpt the drive, or the operating system would need to unlock the drive before Windows itself booted.

There are some screenshots of the process, and it looks like when they said whole disk they meant not just user home folders, but applications and root folders as well.

http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/11/02/28/inside_mac_os_x_10_7_lion_file_vault_full_disk_encryption_and_cloud_key_storage.html